# How to make "yes" the default of rm -i

Tags: rm, defaults

I want to review a long list of files from being deleted, they are not very important so there is no problem if I accidentally delete some of them, but still I want to save some.

How can I call `rm -i ./*` and be prompted `rm: remove regular file 'myfile'?` but set the default to yes as in (Y/n)?

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do? From your post, it appears you just want to review _some_ of the files to keep _some_ of them. In order to change the default, I think you would have to modify the source code and rebuild and deploy it. That, or bind a special keystroke--at which point, for that effort, what's the difference between striking the "Enter" and "y" buttons? So I'm thinking you're better off doing some combination of `ls`, `grep`, and `less` to review your files first, and then pipe in specific results into the `rm` command (with or without the `-i`). Make sense?

Comment: What do you mean by "the default"? You mean you just want to press `Enter` to remove the file?

Comment: @Kusalananda yes, that's what I mean by default, but still get the prompt to choose.

Comment: @tniles I'm trying to delete files from a dir that gets filled daily with news reports for which I have to choose to delete or keep based on the name. This files can be re-downloaded, but the parsing of which to keep and which to delete is a manual process without a filename pattern to grep from.

Comment: @tniles also, I don't want the default to change forever, I thought it more as a flag like `rm -iy` but yes, modifying the source is definitely a way to go, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing stopping you creating your own layer around `rm`, either as a function or a script. (Personally I prefer scripts.)

Copy this to a file `yrm`, put it in a directory that's in your `$PATH` (for example `/usr/local/bin`), and make it executable (`chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/yrm`):

```
#!/bin/sh
#
fails=0    # Number of failures is presented as exit status

for item in "$@"
do
    # Skip directories
    if [ -d "$item" ]
    then
        printf '%s: skipping directory\n' "$item" >&2
        fails=$((fails+1))
        continue
    fi

    # Prompt the user
    printf "%s: remove regular file '%s' (Y/n)? " "${0##*/}" "$item" >&2
    read yn || exit $((fails+1))

    # Either no response or "y" is good enough for deletion
    if [ -z "$yn" ] || [ y = "$yn" ]
    then
        rm "$item" </dev/null    # No -f so we expose error messages
        [ $? -gt 0 ] && fails=$((fails+1))
    fi
done

# Report failures (0=success)
exit $fails
```

You then call it with no flags and one or more files. For example,

```
yrm *.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much, specially for the comments to help me learn!

Comment: I'm pleased to hear the code is useful for you, @cabo. Comments (and indentation) are part of good coding, and a program without them is likely to be close to unmaintainable six months down the road

Answer (score 0):

You can used a case statement,

```
# path of file

file_path=$(ls -ltr | grep "^-" | awk -F" " '{ print $9 }' | grep -i ".txt*")
read -p "enter yes for removing files $file_path" user_inp

# -p :- for user prompt

case ${user_inp}
    in Yes | yes | YES )

        rm  $file_path
        ;;
    *)
        echo "you don't want to delete that file"
esac
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, although the case is reversed to my need (default should be to delete, not to keep) its a good idea.

Comment: Happy learning!!! 

Comment: Thank you, and I'm sorry someone downvoted your answer, it was useful for me so I upvoted but I still don't have enought reputation for my vote to be casted.

Comment: No worries, i am glad to hear that. You can flag the answer, if it helps you some way around by clicking ✅ right side of my answer.

Comment: Not a down-voter but things to improve: (1) use a `#!` first line to declare the shell for which the script is written, (2) either replace `Yes | yes | YES` with a case-insensitive version `[Yy][Ee][Ss]`, or consider mono-casing the user's answer before testing it, (3) piping the output of `ls` to anything is poor practice (for starters, consider user, group and file names that contain spaces), (4) `grep pattern | awk '{action}'` can almost always be replaced with `awk '/pattern/ {action}'`, (5) double-quote your variables each time you use them, (6) consider filenames containing spaces

Comment: Thanks roaima for sharing insight, point which you've listed are quite helpful, i will keep in mind.